# How to animate a vechile icon between cordinates in Open layers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need guidance over animating a car icon between below given coordinates starting from first point. I am using below code and data points but not able to get desired result.

```
var dataSource1 = [{
    "title": 'Duero',
    "lat": 28.631429, 
    "lng": 77.216585,
    "description": 'This is Duero'
}, {
    "title": 'Reyes Catolicos',
    "lat": 28.629364,   
    "lng": 77.211872,
    "description": 'This is Reyes Catolicos'
}, {
    "title": 'Guadarrama',
    "lat": 28.623032, 
    "lng": 77.197852,
    "description": 'This is Guadarrama'
}];

     var iconGeometry = ol.proj.transform([centerPosition.lng, centerPosition.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')

        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: iconGeometry
        });

        iconFeature.setStyle(vehicleStyle);
        //var marker = $scope.createMarker(ol.proj.transform([centerPosition.lng, centerPosition.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), vehicleStyle);

        mapVectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);

        var markers = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.dataPoints, function (value, key) {
            markers.push({ x: value.lat, y: value.lng });
        });

        var i = 0, interval;
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (i == markers.length) {
                i = 0;
            }

            iconGeometry.setCoordinates(new ol.geom.Point([markers[i].y, markers[i].x]));

            i++;
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle with your entire code?

Comment: no i have created local application but it didn't work

Comment: What are the problems with _not able to get desired result_. Is the car moving bad, not moving?! what is the exact issue?

Comment: First issue is that car is not coming at correct location . second is that vehicle is not moving at all. So can i get some example where we have above given points and a car icon move between them.

Comment: I'd be a lot better help if you created a fiddle with your code of the part of movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to do the animation in a `postcompose` event like in this example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/feature-move-animation.html